# File is saved in UTF-8 but strange symbols in Russian language

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am quite new to both Java and Android.

I am trying to initialize String with russian chars

```
    lesson.addUnit(new NounUnit("Schiff", "Корабль", NounUnit.Gender.NEUTRAL));
    lesson.addUnit(new NounUnit("Tafel", "Доска, панель", NounUnit.Gender.FEMININUM));
    lesson.addUnit(new NounUnit("Lineal", "Линейка чертежная", NounUnit.Gender.NEUTRAL));
```

However when I open my debugger I saw some strange `chars`

`[–,ö,–,æ,—,Ä,–,∞,–,±,–,ª,—,å]` instead of `Корабль`

File is in UTF-8 format so this is not an issue
I also tried to set russian locale

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

This does not help.

PS: I am using Android Studio as IDE - probably this is the issue

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: @mipreamble How is that supposed to help?

Comment: When you say the file is encoded as UTF-8 you mean the Java source file, is that correct? If so, what is the native encoding of your platform? My guess is the file is encoded as UTF-8 but the Java compiler does not know that and interprets it as whatever the native platform encoding is.

Comment: @BLaZuRE : Russian language is not available for Locale.

Comment: @mipreamble Look at the second paragraph of your linked documentation.  Look up the ISO mentioned in that paragraph.  It includes the "ru" as a country code.

Comment: @devconsole you are probably right. I am using Android Studio as IDE and trying to set java compiler encoding now...

Answer (score 5):

Often much is misleading, hence the following steps:

1. You can check .java file encoding with an editor like the free [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org).
2. Also the compiler encoding must be set, via the IDE or with `javac -encoding UTF-8`.
3. Try `"\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0430\u043b\u044c"`. This is an editor independent representation of `"Корабль"`, and lets you see whether the .java was encoded right when running.

Comment: I tried "\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0430\u043b\u044c" and it works!! Still, I am sure that my text is in UTF-8 encoding - http://www.flickr.com/photos/gburanov/9369657738/

Comment: Not sure how to set compiler encoding from IDE - I got Android Studio

Comment: Maybe with ` -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` for starting Android Studio. A very short google search did not bring up something else. Sorry, I use no AS.